# Javascript - unexpected end of input error in code

Tags: javascript

I cant get this code to work. It keeps saying unexpected end of input and i cant figure out how to fix it. please help. my code my appear similar to that of the code from codecademys rock paper scissors js code because it is the same code i am trying to custom and modify but i cant get it to work

```
var myFunction = function () {
        var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
        var computerChoice = Math.random();
        if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
            computerChoice = "rock";
        } else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
            computerChoice = "paper";
        } else {
            computerChoice = "scissors";
        }
        console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

        var compare = function (userChoice, computerChoice) {

            if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
                console.log("The result is a tie!")
            } else if (userChoice === "rock") {
                if (computerChoice === scissors) {
                    console.log("rock wins")
                } else {
                    console.log("paper wins")
                }
            } else if (userChoice === "paper") {
                if (computerChoice === "rock") {
                    console.log("paper wins")
                } else {
                    console.log("scissors wins")
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: "Unexpected end of input" means that you began something but then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing a `}` at the end of the code.

Comment: please use comment section for typo

Comment: But that's the answer for his problem.  It's a silly answer but its the answer.